# Proper way to use the 'publisher' property ("The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value.")

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

When I attempt to validate my structured data using Google's Structured Data Testing tool, I get an error:

> The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value.

I am getting that on this line:

```html
<meta itemprop="publisher" content="My Real Name Here" />
```

How do I provide a valid value for this property?

Comment: I found it easier and neater to generate the JSON-LD than add `itemprop`s everywhere - take a look at https://github.com/textbook/bulrush/commit/4728104a8565ef68ab14488e91fd397c3d599362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected value of the [`publisher`](https://schema.org/publisher) property is another item ([`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) or [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person)).

While Schema.org always allows to provide a string value (like you do), Google might require a certain value type for one of their search features (e.g., an [`Organization` value for their Articles rich result for AMP HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615702/1591669)). If you don’t care about (or can’t qualify for) this feature, you can ignore the error in the SDTT.

The problems with using a string value: it’s not clear if the publisher is a person or an organization, and it’s not possible to provide additional data about the publisher.

If you want to provide an item, it could look like:

```html
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <p itemprop="name">NewGuy</p>
</div>
```

```html
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <p itemprop="name">NewGuy Inc.</p>
</div>
```